# Create GCP and Firebase Project with Service Account Without Organization or Folder

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I have a need to use a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Service Account to create Projects programmatically through the Resource Manager REST API.  I want to create Firebase projects in a headless manner.

Our current solution involves imitating a user and browser to achieve this because it does not appear possible to create a Project as a Service Account through the GCP Resource Manager REST API without an Organization (or a Folder, which must be under an Organization).

When I attempt to create a Project as a Service Account, I receive a 403 Bad Request response saying, "Service accounts cannot create projects without a parent".

Attempting to create a Project as a Service Account with an empty Parent produces a 400 Bad Request response saying, "Request contains an invalid argument".

Attempting to create a Project as a Service Account with a Parent whose Type is "organization" without an Id produces a 400 Bad Request response saying, "Parent id must be numeric".

Since I don't have an Organization (calls to organizations.list return `{}`) and I can't create one without a domain, I'm unsure how to proceed down this path.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Q:** How do you create Google Cloud Platform (GCP) projects programmatically using a service account without having a GCP Organization?

**A:** You can't.

---

An actual gmail.com user can create projects in **No Organization**, but a **Service Account** must specify an `organization` or a `folder` as the `parent` at project creation time.

Your current solution of doing it as a user is probably the only real workaround. For that, you would use an **OAuth2 ClientID** and **Secret** to obtain `offline` credentials for the user with the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` scope. Then, you can use that `refresh_token` to generate `access_tokens` that you use to call the [Cloud Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/) to [create projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create).

However, I would make a *strong case* for the **Organization**. If you can obtain a domain, you can use that domain to setup [Cloud Identity](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7319251) and [get an Organization resource](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization#acquiring). Then, you can grant the **Service Account** the **Project Creator** role on your **Organization** resource and it will be able to programmatically create projects.

The win here is that all the projects you create with this **Service Account** will be under a single **Organization** so you can easily grant permissions and manage access across all of the projects in a single place. A new person joins your team, and instead having to grant them access to each of your Firebase or GCP projects one at a time, you can do it by adding a single permission to the **Organization** resource.

More: [Granting, Changing, and Revoking Access to Resources](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access)

Comment: Hi @lukwam, very useful answer but I am still strugling with something: I am trying to create a service accont within a project using the projectCreator role but that is not possible as it is an organization-wide role. Service accounts can't be created at organization level, so, how to create a service account that can create projects?

Comment: That's simple. Instead of granting the permission within the project, under the service account settings, you just use the email address of the service account in the IAM settings for the organization and grant it the Project Creator role there. You can grant any Google user, Group, Domain or Service Account the Project Creator role on your org.