# Making a GCP project in CLI without being able to make a parent as a trial user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I am using a trial version of Google CLoud. In the command line, I am logged in with a .json key file.

```
gcloud projects create training_project
```

returns

> ERROR: (gcloud.projects.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: Service accounts cannot create projects without a parent.

But with a trial account, I can neither create an organization nor a folder to serve as a parent. So, how can I make a new project with the command line interface as a trial user?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53284949/create-gcp-and-firebase-project-with-service-account-without-organization-or-fol) question that concerns doing this with a REST API whereas I want to use the command line interface. Furthermore, that question is not about using a trial account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the error message (this is also documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project_using_a_service_account)), service accounts are not allowed to create projects outside of an organization and must specify the parent resource when creating a project. There is no workaround for this. Since a trial user cannot create an organization as you mentioned, you won't be able to use a service account to create a project.

Having said that, you can create a project via CLI when logged in as a user instead. You can log in by running:

```
gcloud auth login
```

and following the instructions. The `gcloud projects create` command will then run successfully.